# Hover to view animation on a link with CSS

Tags: html, css, animation, hover

I am trying to create an effect on a website like this one: http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menu/css3-animation.html#x .  My code only uses two images at the moment but I'll be using about 10 to 15 for the final animation. I'm trying to achieve the hover to view animation, the second image,not the click effect.  Here's the code:

```css
    
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist li {
      display: block;
      width: 40%;
      height: 150px;
      float: left;
      margin: 1% 3%;
      background-color: rgba(255, 165, 0, 0.11);
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist a {
      margin: 0;
      padding: auto;
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      text-indent: -9000px;
      line-height: 2em;
      font-size: 16px;
      display: block;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .GetOnList {
      position: relative;
      width: 40%;
      height: 150px;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .GetOnList a {
      display: block;
      -webkit-transition: z-index 0.1s linear;
      transtion: z-index 0.1s linear;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .GetOnList a#a1 {
      background: url('images/image1.png');
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .GetOnList a#a2 {
      background: url('images/image2.png');
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .hover a:hover {
      z-index: 20;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .hover a:hover + a {
      z-index: 30;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .hover a#a1 {
      z-index: 20;
    }
    .footer nav ul.homeandlist .hover a#a2 {
      z-index: 10;
    }
```

```html
<div class="footer">

  <nav>

    <p class="footertext">Text will go here</p>
    <div class="clear"></div>
    <ul class="homeandlist">

      <li class="GetOnList hover">
        <a id="a1" href="GetOnList.html">Get On List</a>
        <a id="a2" href="GetOnList.html">Get On List</a>
      </li>

      <li class="HomeLink"><a href="index.html" title="HomeLink">HomeLink</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

 
  </nav>



</div>
```

So far only image 1 shows up but nothing happens on hover.  To me it looks like I'm using the same code as what's used on the website.  Any ideas?
 I've edited the code to remove parts that may not matter.  If more code is needed let me know and I can include what you need, but this should cover it.

Comment: You should put only the code that matters.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a new example: http://jsbin.com/wixume/5/edit

The code uses selectors to

MARK UP:

```
<div class="footer">
  <nav>
    <ul class="homeandlist">
      <li id="addedId"><a id="a1">Get On List</a></li>
      <li id="anotherAddedId"><a id="a2">Get On List</a></li>
      <li id="lastOne"><a id="a3">Get On List</a></li>
    </ul>
  </nav>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.footer nav ul.homeandlist li {
      display: block;
}
.footer nav ul.homeandlist a {
      width: 100%;
      height: 90px;
      display: block;
}
a{
position:absolute;
}
.footer nav ul.homeandlist li {
  position: absolute;
  width: 40%;
  height: 150px;
}
.footer nav ul.homeandlist li {
  display: block;
  -webkit-transition: z-index 0.9s linear;
  transtion: z-index 0.9s linear;
}
#a1 {
  background-color: red;
}
#a2 {
  background-color: yellow;
}
#a3 {
  background-color: blue;
}
#addedId:hover {
  /* Move the first one to the bottom when hover*/
  z-index: 9;
}
li:hover + li {
  /* 
  Move the second li to the top 
  If move mouse, the element below it gets selected and moved to the top. 
  ...and so on for each one below that...
  Once are hovering on the bottom one and we move,
  nothing for a moment has a hover state so we can see the top li.
  And then it starts all back over.
  */
  z-index: 30;
}
#addedId {
  z-index: 20;
}
#anotherAddedId {
  z-index: 19;
}
#lastOne:{
  z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: This seems to work but it is a little different from the site that I referenced.  One problem is the colors seem to change too quickly and when I change the time on the z-index transition property to a higher number, not all of the background colors show up.  Just the red and yellow seem to alternate.  Do you know why the code I have listed isn't working?  Also, what does the .viewwindow .img:hover + .img {z-index:30} part do  Specifically the .img:hover + .img part.  What does the plus sign do?

Comment: Again, what you're doing seems to work.  But I don't think it's going to solve the problem.  The li's need to be separate and it seems like what you've done is put the 3 li's into one spot.  In my case, each li is a link to a separate page so when clicked it will navigate to that part of the site.  Meanwhile, each li will have an animation when hovered.   I haven't completely studied what you just did, but at first glance it looks like it's not going to work as a navigation bar.  But I think you're onto something about the + in the selector.

Comment: Yes, it'll work for your scenario if you get the selectors correct.

Comment: tbh_ I'll study your code again but to me it looks like you have one ul and three li's, however, on the jsbin only one li shows up that the z-index is affecting. In my situation I need 3 list items that have  3 separate transition affects.  The #a1-a3 should only be on one li, not separate li's.  If you look at the referenced site the 11 gif's are assigned to only one div.  In my situation I need the same, 10-15 images assigned to one list item and the transition affect triggered when the image of each li is hovered over. For some reason the .hover a:hover and .hover a:hover + a aren't working

Comment: make a bin out of what you are trying to do please

Comment: I think you will have an ah-ha! moment when you realize where you have to put the first hover event and the + hover event.  Hint: firstimage:hover and image:hover + image.  What type of element this is doesn't matter, all you need is a stack of sequential elements.  Their parent has to be relative positioned, and they have to be absolutely positioned.  By stacked I mean that one after another they must have lower z-indexs.  When the first element in the stack is hovered over, it has to get the lowest x-index. The direct sibling selector, just has to give the highest z-index.

Comment: jbh_ Can you explain what a bin is?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're correct.  On the referenced site the main div: frame hover, contains the images, on my code the li getonlist hover: contains the images but it seems to not behave like a div container.  Is there a reason that the li behaves differently than a div?

Comment: they really should not, for the most part.  I just meant can you try to get something close to what you are working on, on http://jsbin.com so

Comment: tbh_  I created a jsbin, I'm not sure how to add the images.   I changed the code and used a div just like on the referenced website instead of the li I started with and it still doesn't seem to work for me.  Sorry, jsbin is at http://jsbin.com/renele/1/edit

Comment: tbh_   This looks like it works.  I can't figure out what you did differently.  So far I only spotted that you changed the order of the .hover properties.  Also, is it the same code for multiple images 10-20 or more?

Comment: yes it will be the same code, except with the z-indexs of the images will be different.  The main difference is that you were using ids which takes precedence over this type of selector... Don't use ids as your selectors.